# ODBC Connection As Clustered Resource

Tags: sql-server, clustering, linked-server, informix

First step in a long process of creating a Linked Server to an Informix database on a Sql 2008 (Win 2003 x64) cluster.

I was wondering how to go about creating an ODBC connection as a clustered resource, or if I even have to do that.

```
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "__server__" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "__server__". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399)
```

More info: Using IBM's OLEDB and ODBC drivers. It worked on a dev instance but not on a nearly identically-configured prod instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked server "lives" in the clustered SQL Server instance, so whichever node the SQL Server happens to be running on, the linked server should run fine....as long as you've installed the required ODBC/OLEDB driver(s) on each node.

Looking at that error, I'm assuming the linked server doesn't work at all on any node. I suspect you'd have the same problem on a standalone SQL Server too - it seems to me to be a driver issue. Whose OLEDB driver are you using?

I'm sure you've read the following IBM KB:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21195578

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've followed that guide with the same result. I ran this on a test server that is the same OS/SQL versions without any sort of issue. I had to install the MSDASQL 64 bit provider on both. The dev server went just fine, the prod server --- error.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using IBM's Informix CSDK (clientsdk.3.50.FC6DE.WIN)